# How use kendodatepicker with optional formControl fill?

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I'm using the kendo-datepicker and i'm having problems when i save an null date and after try to edit this.

**My html**:

```
<kendo-grid-column width="220" [sortable]="false" field="end_date" [filterable]="false" title="Data final">

  <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
    {{ dataItem.end_date | date:'shortDate' }}
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template kendoGridEditTemplate let-dataItem>
      <div class="whole-cell">
        <kendo-datepicker
          [min]="dataMinima"
          [formControl]="formGroup.get('end_date')"
        ></kendo-datepicker>
      </div>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-column>
```

This is my function that create my `form group`:

```
const createFormGroup = (dataItem?: ClasseProfessor) => {
  if (dataItem) {
    return new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(dataItem.id),
      class_id: new FormControl(dataItem.class_id),
      user_id: new FormControl(dataItem.user_id, Validators.required),
      start_date: new FormControl(new Date(dataItem.start_date), Validators.required),
      end_date: new FormControl(new Date(dataItem.end_date)),
    });
  } else {
    return new FormGroup({
      class_id: new FormControl(null),
      user_id: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      start_date: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      end_date: new FormControl(null)
    });
  }
};
```

My **end_date** is optional, i save with null value in database, but when i edit my column the `formGroup` make the `new Date(null)` and i get the value `31/12/1969`

I tried to make this way too:

```
const createFormGroup = (dataItem?: ClasseProfessor) => {
  if (dataItem) {
    return new FormGroup({
      id: new FormControl(dataItem.id),
      class_id: new FormControl(dataItem.class_id),
      user_id: new FormControl(dataItem.user_id, Validators.required),
      start_date: new FormControl(dataItem.start_date, Validators.required),
      end_date: new FormControl(dataItem.end_date),
    });
  } else {
    return new FormGroup({
      class_id: new FormControl(null),
      user_id: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      start_date: new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
      end_date: new FormControl(null)
    });
  }
};
```

But i receive one error saying that the `kendo-datepicker` expect a `Date` instance.

How i can fix this?
I need when i click in edit button show an empty date instead the value of `new Date(null)`

Comment: What do you mean by 'empty date'?

Comment: the default selection of datapicker, without one date

Comment: `new Date(null)` returns the smallest possible date in Unix time, which Jan 1st, 1970.  You are seeing 31/12/1969 due to your timezone, most likely. Not sure what exactly you are expecting.